# How to use ANOVA to this matrix?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, anova, manova

I have a matrix `A`, the size of which is `1200*4500 double`. Where 
the `1200` represents the number of time points and `4500` denotes the
number of features. Beside this, I still have a label class `L`,
the size of which is `1200*1 double`. The values in `L` are from `1` to `6`,
I want to apply `ANOVA` on matrix `A`. I expect to get a matrix `B`, 
the size of which is still `1200*4500 double`. The value for each 
feature in matrix `B` is a p value.

Note: when I use anova1 to do this problem, I can only get a vector B, not a matrix B. Actually I want to get a matrix B.
Can anyone give me a help? Thanks!

Comment: This might help [ANOVA MATLAB](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/analysis-of-variance-and-covariance.html)

Comment: @Umar, when I use anova1 to do this problem, I can only get a vector B, not a matrix B. Actually I want to get a matrix B. Can you help me?

Comment: @rayryeng, can you answer this question? Thank you so much!